# Raspberry Pi matplotlib install failed

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm struggling with instalation of Matplotlib at Rpi3. I'm using Python3.12. Previously I was trying install at my virtual env with fail result. Now I'm trying at 'default' site. Currently instalation contourpy is ongoing but maybe someone will see something I cannot find and give me a hint? I will be appriceated.

```
rpi@pv:~ $ python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages (23.                                                                                             3.2)
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/setuptools/setuptools-69.0.3-py3-n                                                                                             one-any.whl (819 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 819.5/819.5 kB 2.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/wheel/wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.wh                                                                                             l (65 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 65.4/65.4 kB 489.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-69.0.3 wheel-0.42.0
rpi@pv:~ $ python -m pip install matplotlib
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-3.8.2.tar.gz (35.9 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 35.9/35.9 MB 2.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Downloading contourpy-1.2.0.tar.gz (13.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.5/13.5 MB 4.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [96 lines of output]
      + meson setup /tmp/pip-install-p7t2kag3/contourpy_fe3d3e65dc2948fd9f631a7e                                                                                             6ea21ead /tmp/pip-install-p7t2kag3/contourpy_fe3d3e65dc2948fd9f631a7e6ea21ead/.m                                                                                             esonpy-uwiz7cdw -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv -                                                                                             -native-file=/tmp/pip-install-p7t2kag3/contourpy_fe3d3e65dc2948fd9f631a7e6ea21ea                                                                                             d/.mesonpy-uwiz7cdw/meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.3.1
      Source dir: /tmp/pip-install-p7t2kag3/contourpy_fe3d3e65dc2948fd9f631a7e6e                                                                                             a21ead
      Build dir: /tmp/pip-install-p7t2kag3/contourpy_fe3d3e65dc2948fd9f631a7e6ea                                                                                             21ead/.mesonpy-uwiz7cdw
      Build type: native build
      Project name: contourpy
      Project version: 1.2.0
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 10.2.1 "c++ (Raspbian 10.2.1-6                                                                                             +rpi1) 10.2.1 20210110")
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.35.2
      Host machine cpu family: arm
      Host machine cpu: armv7l
      Program python found: YES (/usr/bin/python)
      Found pkg-config: YES (/usr/bin/pkg-config) 0.29.2
      pybind11-config found: YES (/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/bin/pybind                                                                                             11-config) 2.11.1
      Run-time dependency pybind11 found: YES 2.11.1
      Configuring _build_config.py using configuration
      Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.12
      Build targets in project: 1

      contourpy 1.2.0

        Build config
          host_cpu    : armv7l
          build_cpu   : armv7l
          cross_build : false
          optimization: 3

        User defined options
          Native files: /tmp/pip-install-p7t2kag3/contourpy_fe3d3e65dc2948fd9f63                                                                                             1a7e6ea21ead/.mesonpy-uwiz7cdw/meson-python-native-file.ini
          buildtype   : release
          vsenv       : true
          b_ndebug    : if-release
          b_vscrt     : md

      Found ninja-1.11.1.git.kitware.jobserver-1 at /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/                                                                                             normal/bin/ninja

      Visual Studio environment is needed to run Ninja. It is recommended to use                                                                                              Meson wrapper:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/bin/meson compile -C .
      + /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/normal/bin/ninja -v
      [1/14] c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I.                                                                                             ./src -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/                                                                                             python3.12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-colo                                                                                             r=always -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17                                                                                              -O3 -fPIC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux                                                                                             -gnueabihf.so.p/line_type.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabi                                                                                             hf.so.p/line_type.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p                                                                                             /line_type.cpp.o -c ../src/line_type.cpp
      [2/14] c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I.                                                                                             ./src -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/                                                                                             python3.12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-colo                                                                                             r=always -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17                                                                                              -O3 -fPIC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux                                                                                             -gnueabihf.so.p/fill_type.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabi                                                                                             hf.so.p/fill_type.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p                                                                                             /fill_type.cpp.o -c ../src/fill_type.cpp
      [3/14] c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I.                                                                                             ./src -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/                                                                                             python3.12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-colo                                                                                             r=always -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17                                                                                              -O3 -fPIC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux                                                                                             -gnueabihf.so.p/outer_or_hole.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnu                                                                                             eabihf.so.p/outer_or_hole.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueab                                                                                             ihf.so.p/outer_or_hole.cpp.o -c ../src/outer_or_hole.cpp
      [4/14] c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I.                                                                                             ./src -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/                                                                                             python3.12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-colo                                                                                             r=always -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17                                                                                              -O3 -fPIC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux                                                                                             -gnueabihf.so.p/converter.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabi                                                                                             hf.so.p/converter.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p                                                                                             /converter.cpp.o -c ../src/converter.cpp
      FAILED: src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p/converter.cpp.                                                                                             o
      c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I../src -                                                                                             I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/python3                                                                                             .12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-color=alway                                                                                             s -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17 -O3 -fP                                                                                             IC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueab                                                                                             ihf.so.p/converter.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p                                                                                             /converter.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p/conver                                                                                             ter.cpp.o -c ../src/converter.cpp
      c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
      compilation terminated.
      [5/14] c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I.                                                                                             ./src -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/                                                                                             python3.12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-colo                                                                                             r=always -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17                                                                                              -O3 -fPIC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux                                                                                             -gnueabihf.so.p/chunk_local.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnuea                                                                                             bihf.so.p/chunk_local.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.                                                                                             so.p/chunk_local.cpp.o -c ../src/chunk_local.cpp
      FAILED: src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p/chunk_local.cp                                                                                             p.o
      c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I../src -                                                                                             I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/python3                                                                                             .12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-color=alway                                                                                             s -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17 -O3 -fP                                                                                             IC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueab                                                                                             ihf.so.p/chunk_local.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so                                                                                             .p/chunk_local.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p/ch                                                                                             unk_local.cpp.o -c ../src/chunk_local.cpp
      c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
      compilation terminated.
      [6/14] c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I.                                                                                             ./src -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/                                                                                             python3.12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-colo                                                                                             r=always -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17                                                                                              -O3 -fPIC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux                                                                                             -gnueabihf.so.p/mpl2005.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf                                                                                             .so.p/mpl2005.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p/mpl                                                                                             2005.cpp.o -c ../src/mpl2005.cpp
      [7/14] c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I.                                                                                             ./src -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/                                                                                             python3.12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-colo                                                                                             r=always -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17                                                                                              -O3 -fPIC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux                                                                                             -gnueabihf.so.p/mpl2005_original.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-                                                                                             gnueabihf.so.p/mpl2005_original.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-                                                                                             gnueabihf.so.p/mpl2005_original.cpp.o -c ../src/mpl2005_original.cpp
      [8/14] c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I.                                                                                             ./src -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/                                                                                             python3.12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-colo                                                                                             r=always -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17                                                                                              -O3 -fPIC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux                                                                                             -gnueabihf.so.p/mpl2014.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf                                                                                             .so.p/mpl2014.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p/mpl                                                                                             2014.cpp.o -c ../src/mpl2014.cpp
      In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/vector:72,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/python3.12/s                                                                                             ite-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../detail/common.h:314,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/python3.12/s                                                                                             ite-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../attr.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/python3.12/s                                                                                             ite-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/class.h:12,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/python3.12/s                                                                                             ite-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:13,
                       from ../src/common.h:4,
                       from ../src/contour_generator.h:4,
                       from ../src/mpl2014.h:145,
                       from ../src/mpl2014.cpp:8:
      /usr/include/c++/10/bits/vector.tcc: In member function ‘void std::vector<                                                                                             _Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...)                                                                                              [with _Args = {const double&, const double&}; _Tp = contourpy::mpl2014::XY; _Al                                                                                             loc = std::allocator<contourpy::mpl2014::XY>]’:
      /usr/include/c++/10/bits/vector.tcc:426:7: note: parameter passing for arg                                                                                             ument of type ‘std::vector<contourpy::mpl2014::XY>::iterator’ changed in GCC 7.1
        426 |       vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
            |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /usr/include/c++/10/bits/vector.tcc: In member function ‘void contourpy::m                                                                                             pl2014::Mpl2014ContourGenerator::get_point_xy(contourpy::index_t, contourpy::mpl                                                                                             2014::ContourLine&) const’:
      /usr/include/c++/10/bits/vector.tcc:121:21: note: parameter passing for ar                                                                                             gument of type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<contourpy::mpl2014::XY*, std::vecto                                                                                             r<contourpy::mpl2014::XY> >’ changed in GCC 7.1
        121 |    _M_realloc_insert(end(), std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
            |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /usr/include/c++/10/bits/vector.tcc: In member function ‘unsigned int cont                                                                                             ourpy::mpl2014::Mpl2014ContourGenerator::follow_boundary(contourpy::mpl2014::Con                                                                                             tourLine&, contourpy::mpl2014::QuadEdge&, const double&, const double&, unsigned                                                                                              int, const contourpy::mpl2014::QuadEdge&)’:
      /usr/include/c++/10/bits/vector.tcc:121:21: note: parameter passing for ar                                                                                             gument of type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<contourpy::mpl2014::XY*, std::vecto                                                                                             r<contourpy::mpl2014::XY> >’ changed in GCC 7.1
        121 |    _M_realloc_insert(end(), std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
            |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      /usr/include/c++/10/bits/vector.tcc: In member function ‘void std::vector<                                                                                             _Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...)                                                                                              [with _Args = {const contourpy::mpl2014::XY&}; _Tp = contourpy::mpl2014::XY; _A                                                                                             lloc = std::allocator<contourpy::mpl2014::XY>]’:
      /usr/include/c++/10/bits/vector.tcc:426:7: note: parameter passing for arg                                                                                             ument of type ‘std::vector<contourpy::mpl2014::XY>::iterator’ changed in GCC 7.1
        426 |       vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
            |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/vector:67,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/python3.12/s                                                                                             ite-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../detail/common.h:314,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/python3.12/s                                                                                             ite-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../attr.h:13,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/python3.12/s                                                                                             ite-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/class.h:12,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/python3.12/s                                                                                             ite-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:13,
                       from ../src/common.h:4,
                       from ../src/contour_generator.h:4,
                       from ../src/mpl2014.h:145,
                       from ../src/mpl2014.cpp:8:
      /usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h: In member function ‘pybind11::tuple                                                                                              contourpy::mpl2014::Mpl2014ContourGenerator::lines(const double&)’:
      /usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:1198:21: note: parameter passing for                                                                                              argument of type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<contourpy::mpl2014::XY*, std::ve                                                                                             ctor<contourpy::mpl2014::XY> >’ changed in GCC 7.1
       1198 |    _M_realloc_insert(end(), __x);
            |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
      [9/14] c++ -Isrc/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p -Isrc -I.                                                                                             ./src -I/usr/local/include/python3.12 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-zfofyfpr/overlay/lib/                                                                                             python3.12/site-packages/pybind11/include -fvisibility=hidden -fdiagnostics-colo                                                                                             r=always -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Werror -std=c++17                                                                                              -O3 -fPIC -DCONTOURPY_VERSION=1.2.0 -MD -MQ src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux                                                                                             -gnueabihf.so.p/serial.cpp.o -MF src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.                                                                                             so.p/serial.cpp.o.d -o src/_contourpy.cpython-312-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so.p/seria                                                                                             l.cpp.o -c ../src/serial.cpp
      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit                                                                                             h pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Earlier before I was trying install Matplotlib at virtual env.
My expaectation - install this package sucessfully.